# Jackson - Processing JSON with multiple types

Tags: java, json, jackson

Say I have a JSON file that looks like this:

```
{
"response" : [
    {
        "id" : "10",
        "period" : "month",
        "values" : [
             {
                 "value" : 100,
                 "date" : "2013-05-10"
             }
        ],
        "parent" : "1"
    },
    {
        "id" : "10",
        "period" : "day",
        "values" : [
             {
                 "value" : {
                        "foo" : 10,
                        "bar" : 11,
                        "etc" : 4
                 },
                 "date" : "2013-05-10"
             }
        ],
        "parent" : "1"
    },{
        "id" : "13",
        "period" : "year",
        "values" : [
             {
                 "value" : {
                        "info" : 1,
                        "pages" : 10,
                        "etc" : 4
                 },
                 "date" : "2013-05-10"
             }
        ],
        "parent" : "1"
    }
]
}
```

Notice the 'values' part can either be a single value, or an object (which is unique).

I want to use the Jackson ObjectMapper to easily map this to a POJO.

What I have so far:

```
public class Response
{
    List<ResponseEntry> response;
    /*getters + setters */

    public static class ResponseEntry
    {
         private String id;
         private String period;
         private String parent;
         private List<Value> values;
         /*setters + getters*/

         public static class Value
         {
             private Object value;
             private String date;
             /*setters+getters*/
         }
    }
}
```

To map the response, I just specify the file I want and tell ObjectMapper to map to the 'Response' class

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
Response r = mapper.readValues(json, Response.class);
```

This works, but is there a better way than just using 'Object' to hold 'value'? Since 'value' can be either a single value or an object, I'm having a bit of difficult figuring out what it should be. I'm certain there is a polymorphic way of handling this, but I've looked and couldn't find anything that worked. I'm pretty stuck and I would appreciate any help.

Comment: Actually you can use `JsonDeserializer`. Look here how it can be achieved: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13891415/deserializing-json-with-multiple-types-in-one-field

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately, with the structure of the JSON you are handling, the only way to deserialize it is to have the `value` attribute be type `Object`. However, once the JSON is deserialized, you can easily figure out whether `value` is an object or a single value.

Notice that JSON only supports five data types: objects (Map in java), arrays, strings, numeric and boolean. It looks like in your case, `value` would most likely be either a number or a map of numbers; then you have two possibilities to check for. Using a quick `instanceof` comparison, you should be able to figure out what type of value it is.

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
Response r = mapper.readValues(json, Response.class);
Value val = r.response.get(0).values.get(0);
if (val.value instanceof Map)
    ; // multiple
else
    ; // single
```