# Fasterxml Jackson convert json to java pojo

Tags: java, json, jackson2

My application is consuming a third party API which produces a JSON response. I have mapped relevant pojo classes to the respective JSON responses. But I have a difficulty with mapping a particular response which has a property "message" that is sometimes String and sometimes Object.

The datatype of the property "message" changes for particular requests for the same API call. I don't want to parse the JSON string using JSONObject or a JSONArray instead I want to map this response to a pojo class.

Can anybody please help me with this? Thanks!

**Response 1**

```
{
    "Message": {
        "name": "John Doe"
    }
}
```

**Response 2**

```
{
    "Message": "some error message"
}
```

I asked the API provider to change this behaviour but he/she refuses to my request saying he does not have control over what is produced in the json response.

Comment: Use Map<String,String> or <String,Object> for getting response and now you will get  response object as Map then use condition statement and based on tht condition convert it into pojo by using ObjectMapper

Comment: I think this should solve your problem https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13891415/deserializing-json-with-multiple-types-in-one-field